# How do I change a wordpress dev site url that was overwritten by live site backup

Tags: php, wordpress

We have a dev site `www.dev.site.co.za` & a live site `www.site.co.za`.
I wanted the dev site updated to be a current replica of the live site, so our hosting provider copied it over.
But now when if you go to `www.dev.site.co.za`, you are "redirected" to `www.site.co.za`. I have tried changing the `siteurl` in *phpmyadmin* but that hasn't resolved the issue.

Is there somewhere else the url needs to corrected and is there anything else I need to do to make sure the dev site is a completely separate environment to the live site so I can safely fiddle without damaging the live site?

Comment: There might be hardcoded URLs in your template files too, do you have a tool to search for `www.site.co.za` in all your template files? the .htaccess file can contain some too

Comment: might be in wp-config file - you can define home and site url in there as well

Comment: What I would do is migrate to the new environment and like that you have two environment(for future changes you can test it somewhere else live).

Answer (score 1):

wordpress not only uses the database in PHPMyAdmin for the url.

As mentioned in the [official documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) there are several files that can include the url:

- the **wp-config.php** (wordpress file)
- the **functions.php** (theme file)

Check these and have a look for the url address.
Have a look at the **.htaccess** file!

Also:
Helpful for that issue (e.g. restoring a wordpress page on another server) is the plugin BackupBuddy. It is one of the most well known plugins for wordpress. (Know right now that it is a paid version! But as always there are [others](http://appointzilla.com/5-free-alternatives-to-backupbuddy/) with the functionality).

It allows you to backup and restore your page on a new system. You can initially set your *new* desired address for the system then.
Maybe it is worth a look!

Answer (score 1):

For rectifying your dev site issue, you can try this.

Following is the URL to a simple utility via which you can replace some value in your database with some desired value.
https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB

- Download the utility (zip file).
- Upload it to your dev site root location and unzip it there. So that the the URL of the unzipped folder becomes: www.dev.site.co.za/Search-Replace-DB-master/.
- Visiting that URL will show you the screen with options to replace some values in your database with desired values.
- This utility automatically selected the connected database.
- Put the URL of your live site in the field to replace.
- Put the URL of your dev site in the field to replace with.
- Choose the Dry Run option to see what all tables and columns will be affected.
- Once you see the results and know what is changing then you the click on Live Run.
- Clicking on Live Run will change all the URL of your live site in dev site database with URL of your dev site.
- Once the changes are done you can delete this folder.

Hope this will at least resolve the problem of redirection of dev site to live site.

Comment: `"Once the changes are done you can delete this folder."` You should definetly delete this folder afterwards :-D

Answer (score 0):

Once the new site is built you can then migrate(move, copy) it to the live site's location. There are some tools out there to help with moving the site you can use once the site is done. Some require a plugin to be installed to do that though. For example magicmigration can be used to move the completed site to a new location (that one specifically doesn't take extra installs). It is also possible to manually migrate the site though depending on the situation and know-how that can be a bit much for some people.